# Redshift - Simplify Query Plan

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two tables in Redshift that I am trying to do a join on to get zip code demographics based on a users normalized ip address. By normalized address, I mean that it is concerted to a uniform length string that has the periods stripped out and can be directly compared to one another. For example, this is applied to all ips before any joins are done and is stored in the tables:

```
lpad(split_part(ip, '.', 1), 3, '0') ||
lpad(split_part(ip, '.', 2), 3, '0') ||
lpad(split_part(ip, '.', 3), 3, '0') ||
lpad(split_part(ip, '.', 4), 3, '0')
```

so `209.170.151.71` would be transformed into `209170151071`.

I have two tables. This first is visitor_details which contains the following:

```
-----------------------------
| visitor_id |      ip      |
-----------------------------
|      1     | 209170151071 |
|      2     | 123170167071 |
      ...           ...
| 50000000   | 001213020341 |
-----------------------------
```

The I have a table called geo_ip which has the following structure:

```
----------------------------------------
|    start_ip |    end_ip      |  zip  |
----------------------------------------
|209170151071 | 209170151071   | 11101 |
|309170151071 | 409170151071   | 11102 |
      ...           ...           ...
|509170151071 | 609170151071   | 11103 |
----------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
WITH vd AS (
  SELECT visitor_id,
         ip_address as c_ip
  FROM dev.visitor_details
)
SELECT
  visitor_id,
  c_ip,
  g.*
FROM
  vd
JOIN
  dev.geo_ip g
  ON vd.c_ip BETWEEN g.startip and g.endip
LIMIT 500;
```

The sort keys on geo ip are an interleaved sort key using both startip and endip. The table also doesn't seem to be skewed. However, running the query results in a very long execution time (never completed). Looking at the explain I see the following:

```
XN Limit  (cost=0.00..245.17 rows=500 width=238)
   ->  XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=0.00..18442148764959.20 rows=37610983146614 width=238)
         Join Filter: ((("inner".startip)::text <= ("outer".ip_address)::text) AND (("inner".endip)::text >= ("outer".ip_address)::text))
         ->  XN Seq Scan on visitor_details  (cost=0.00..596971.20 rows=59697120 width=72)
         ->  XN Seq Scan on geo_ip g  (cost=0.00..56702.71 rows=5670271 width=166)
 ----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----
```

What is odder, is that if I hard code an ip address for the join the query plan looks normal.

Can anyone make any suggestions on how to either optimize the query of the table setup to make it run efficiently?

***UPDATE***

I made the changes suggested by the first response, but I am still seeing the nested loop. All IPs are now bigints and the with statement was removed.

```
explain SELECT 
    vd.visitor_id,
    vd.ip_address,
    gi.zip
FROM
dev.visitor_details2 vd
JOIN dev.geo_ip3 gi ON vd.ip BETWEEN gi.startip and gi.endip
LIMIT 500;


                                               QUERY PLAN                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 XN Limit  (cost=0.00..136.62 rows=500 width=51)
   ->  XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=0.00..10276958524959.20 rows=37610983146614 width=51)
         Join Filter: (("inner".startip <= "outer".ip) AND ("inner".endip >= "outer".ip))
         ->  XN Seq Scan on visitor_details2 vd  (cost=0.00..596971.20 rows=59697120 width=52)
         ->  XN Seq Scan on geo_ip3 gi  (cost=0.00..56702.71 rows=5670271 width=23)
 ----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----
(6 rows)
```

***UPDATE 2***
Here are the table definitions to confirm that they are both bigint:

```
master=# \d dev.visitor_details2;
          Table "dev.visitor_details2"
   Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
------------+------------------------+-----------
 id         | integer                | not null
 visitor_id | character varying(108) | 
 ip         | bigint                 | 
 ip_address | character varying(192) | 
 domain     | integer                | 
Indexes:
    "visitor_details2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

master=# \d dev.geo_ip3;
                Table "dev.geo_ip3"
    Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------------+------------------------+-----------
 startip      | bigint                 | 
 endip        | bigint                 | 
 country      | character varying(16)  | 
 region       | character varying(32)  | 
 city         | character varying(32)  | 
 zip          | character varying(16)  | 
 latitude     | double precision       | 
 longitude    | double precision       | 
 areacode     | integer                | 
 metrocode    | integer                | 
 timezone     | character varying(32)  | 
 isp          | character varying(128) | 
 organization | character varying(128) | 
 netspeed     | character varying(32)  | 
 domain       | character varying(128) |
```

Comment: Are your stats up to date?  What are the number of rows in each table?  How are your tables distributed?

Comment: Yea, I ran analyze on the tables before the explain with an analyze_threshold_percent set to 0 to force the analyze to run. visitor_details2 has 59697122 rows and geo_ip3 has 5670271 rows. The geo_ip3 table is distributed via the startip and visitor_details table is distributed via the visitor_id. RedShift reports that the skew for geo_ip3 is 1.0000 and the skew for visitor_details2 is 1.0064. The pct_stats_off for both is 0.00 and the pct_unsorted for both is 0.00.

Comment: `\d` alone doesn't give the full DDL.  You're not showing the sort key, dist key, etc.  Please can we see the actual create table statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using the `with` statement here. Did you read the documentation?
I guess what's happening is, that it's executing the query in the with block for every entry in the visitor_detail table and then has to broadcast this to the other node `XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER`.
Also you can see it's joining on text `Join Filter: ((("inner".startip)::text`.
You should consider changing the data type of the ip_address to `BIGINT`.

I'd write the query this way:

```
SELECT 
    vd.visitor_id,
    vd.ip_address,
    gi.zip
FROM
dev.visitor_details vd
JOIN geo_ip gi ON vd.ip_address BETWEEN gi.start_ip and gi.end_ip
LIMIT 500;
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the way Redshift handels joins on 'between' are pretty expensive. Did you think about adding all ip addresses in these range explicit and use the ip_address as the sort key? I know this table can become quite large in number of rows, but if you use proper compression (DELTA32K for ip and runlength for zip) and a distribution to all nodes, this might be a solution.

Comment: I did a variation where everything was precast as a bigint. Even without the with statement I am still seeing the nested loop. See the updated question for more details. Thanks.

Comment: @user2694306 Did you ensure the data type is BIGINT in both tables?  I recommend supplying the Full DDL for both tables so we can see datatype, sort key, dist key, etc, etc.

Comment: They are both bigint, I've added the full ddls for both tables. Note that the second explain that I was using used 'ip' from the visitor_details2 table.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar. It would be around 4.3 billion rows, but may be a viable option.

Comment: Let me know when you found a solution that worked for you. quite interesting topic.