# Redshift ----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to write a query in redshift which has a "BETWEEN" within an inner join. In Redshift I understand this can be quite expensive but I can't figure out another way of writing it. It seems that I have the exact same query as the pasted link but in that question showed no answers. Does anyone know how to rewrite this query to avoid a Cartesian product?

[Redshift - Simplify Query Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694460/redshift-simplify-query-plan)

```
select a.ip, a.userid, b.city, b.country, b.ip_start, b.ip_end
from usertable a 
left join ip_table on a.ip between b.ip_start and b.ip_end
```

In the case of applying data types and sort/distribution keys I've tried number of possibilities but nothing seems to help my query.

- `ip and ip_start/ip_end = bigint`
- sort keys applied on `ip_start/ip_end` and `ip`
- distribution key applied on `ip` and `ip_start`

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use with `union all` and window functions  To get the `ip` range.  The idea is to combine the two tables and then use `union all` to bring together the most recent `ip_start` value.

You can then bring in additional columns by joining back to the original tables:

```
with ui as (
      select u.user_id, u.ip, null as ip_start
      from usertable u
      union all
      select null, i.ip_start, i.ip_start
      from ip_table i
     )
select u.*, ip.*
from (select u.user_id,
             max(ip_start) over (order by ip) as ip_start
      from ui
     ) ui join
     usertable u
     on u.user_id = ui.user_id join
     ip_table ip
     on ip.ip_start = ui.ip_start;
```

Note that this assumes that the ranges are not overlapping, which is typically of ip ranges.

This also does not check `ip_end`.  You can do that if you are concerned about ip addresses that are not in your lookup table.  You would filter them out just by added `where u.ip <= ip.ip_end`.

Comment: can you explain how you are joining back with the second half of the query?
select u.*, ip.*
from (select u.user_id,
             max(ip_start) over (order by ip) as ip_start
      from ui
     ) ui join
     usertable u
     on u.user_id join
     ip_table ip
     on ip.ip_start = ui.ip_start;